# Spring Web Service HTTPS

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have configured SSL for my spring boot webservice as follows:

```
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig {

    final String keystoreFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/ws.jks";
    final String keystorePass = "mypass";
    final String keystoreAlias = "myalias";

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector createSslConnector() {

        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
        try {

            connector.setScheme("https");
            connector.setSecure(true);
            connector.setPort(8443);
            protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
            protocol.setKeystoreFile(keystoreFile);
            protocol.setKeystorePass(keystorePass);
            protocol.setKeyAlias(keystoreAlias);

            return connector;

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            throw new IllegalStateException("can't access keystore: [" + "keystore"
                    + "] or truststore: [" + "keystore" + "]", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the servlet I get the following output, as expected:

> Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http 8443/https

So the configuration was obviously detected. All endpoints work as expected via 8080 with no HTTPS, unfortunately attempting to access the endpoints over HTTPS on 8443 result in a NO_RESPONSE error, i.e. the connection is closed by the web service immediately upon request.

Have spent a few hours trying different configurations, have tried a self signed key/keystore, all resulted in the same problem.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Marc

Comment: Have you tried to debug the `SSL` Handshake. On *nix Systems you can use a tool like OpenSSL `OpenSSL s_client -connect www.test.com:443 -prexit` to see what's happening during the handshake. You can also try to trace the SSL Handshake on the Server side by setting the Java Options when you start your Application to `-Djavax.net.debug=all` `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:data`. See also [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

Comment: @andih - Yes there are some errors in the SSL connection debug. Specifically unable to verify the first certificate. Possibly missing some intermediary certificates?

Comment: What do you mean with "first certificate"? The root certificate? You either need to import the certificate(s) into your clients  keystore / trust store ... or to configure the client to ignore certificate errors.